# unable to change value of a key value pair array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am not very familiar with php arrays and trying to change value of an array generated from laravel collection with no success.
Here is the code :

```
$items = Purchase::find($id)->items->toArray();
foreach ($items as $i) {
    $i['itemdesc'] = "Test";
}
info($items);
```

The $items array looks like this :

```
[2021-06-05 17:29:20] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'itemcode' => '54',
    'itemdesc' => 'FARROAD 225/40ZR18  FRD26 92W XL',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'itemcode' => '141',
    'itemdesc' => 'TRACKMAX 225/40ZR19 X-PRIVILO TX3 93Y XL',
  ),
```

The values for itemdesc are not getting changed.
If I add info($i) inside the foreach loop I can see that the value is changed.
Can someone help what is wrong in above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a `&`, that will allow you to [loop the array by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($items as & $i) {
//                 ^
//                 |
//                here
```

Comment: This is a duplicate that already has plenty of answers.

Comment: Yep, you're right

Answer (score 0):

I think  you can use transform using collection.

> The transform method iterates over the collection and calls the given
> callback with each item in the collection. The items in the collection
> will be replaced by the values returned by the callback:

**Side Note**

> Unlike most other collection methods, transform modifies the
> collection itself. If you wish to create a new collection instead, use
> the map method.

```
$items = Purchase::find($id)->items;
$items->transform(function($item) {
        $item->itemdesc="test";
        return $item;
    });

info($items);
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-transform